# Image uploading Formgroup Angular6

Tags: html, angular, angular6

Is there a way to upload multiple images through a formgroup with Angular6?

[Current formgroup setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stSzu.png)

I am thinking of a field where people can upload pictures of the car, and drag them around to choose the order they will appear in.
I am planning to use the first image as the "profile" picture of the car.

Comment: You can, but it requires quite a lot of work (well at least it would not be convenient to do it in SO). I suggest you read this article which might help you a lot : https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-file-upload-component-with-express (you can skip the express set-up).

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at it.

Comment: @BernardPagoaga The article you posted helped out a lot.
But it does not solve my issue where the image need to show, and it lets the user drag them around to determine order.
Got any examples or articles on that?

Comment: @BernardPagoaga Or would you recommend another approach to achieve the desired results? Im open to any suggestions.

Comment: No sorry I don't have any suggestion rn, but you could probably find some kind of drag and drop plugin to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your time